# Loop in rule to create facts in CLIPS

Tags: loops, rule, clips

I have the following facts:

```
(deffacts Cars
    (color red)
    (color green)
    (color yellow)
    (doors three)
    (doors five)
)
```

Is is possible to create defrule to loop through the facts to create new facts like (car red three), (car red five), (car green three), (...), for all the possible combinations of color and doors?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CLIPS> 
(deffacts Cars
   (color red)
   (color green)
   (color yellow)
   (doors three)
   (doors five))
CLIPS>    
(defrule combinations
   (color ?color)
   (doors ?doors)
   =>
   (assert (car ?color ?doors)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (color red)
f-2     (color green)
f-3     (color yellow)
f-4     (doors three)
f-5     (doors five)
f-6     (car red five)
f-7     (car green five)
f-8     (car yellow five)
f-9     (car red three)
f-10    (car green three)
f-11    (car yellow three)
For a total of 12 facts.
CLIPS>
```